# Possible disease of Kramer?

Tags: character, seinfeld

Throughout all episodes of Seinfeld, we've seen that Kramer might have a neurological disorder, which could explain why he falls so frequently. However, the writers did not clarify which disease that was.

Is there any evidence that he has a disorder, and if so, what that disorder might be?

Comment: Well, you may as well ask if Chaplin's characters had deformed feet or if Jim Carrey's characters are schizophrenic. Clumsiness, goofiness, pratfalls, exaggerated gestures and facial tics are all merely symptoms of common slapticitis.

Comment: yes, sure. Is my question off topic?

Comment: I don't really know. Even Elaine wondered about it in *The Kiss Hello*. But if *I'd* answer it, I doubt my answer would be any different.

Comment: @MertAktaş No, not really off-topic, even if the only answer is just *"he had no desease"*.

Comment: According to [time magazine](http://time.com/3652039/seinfeld-psychiatric-disorders/) he possesses schizoid personality traits.

Comment: And try to work [this one](http://www.strongmindbraveheart.com/winnie-pooh-characters-mental-disorders/) in somehow. ;)

Comment: There wasn't ever any specific indication that I know of that he had a disease. Simply that he was an eccentric person.

Comment: He sure had a rough childhood as there are scattered references to that by Kramer himself.